# Write-S3Object : The process cannot access the file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having trouble uploading a file from an aws instance using the powershell Write-S3Object command.  I *do* have a handle open on the 'c:\work\log_instance2.txt' file since I have a running python script and this is the log file.  Is this the expected behaviour of the Write-S3Object?  How can I upload the file when the python app is still running?

```
Write-S3Object : The process cannot access the file
'c:\work\log_instance2.txt' because it is being used by another process.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-S3Object -BucketName 'catcfs' -File 'c:\\work\\log_instance2.txt' -Key
'Un ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...eS3ObjectCm
   dlet:WriteS3ObjectCmdlet) [Write-S3Object], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.
   S3.WriteS3ObjectCmdlet
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an iffy one.  Hit the same error myself, when writing back a log file to s3.

FUN FACT - If using Start-Transcript -path "D:\ServerSetupLog.txt" -append, Write-Output doesn't work properly in PS 5 and above.  It holds the transcript file open so you need to use Write-Information instead.  Only, Write-Information doesn't echo back to the console.  However, this wasn't the problem/fix.

I used the sysinternals util procexp64 (download or run it from https://live.sysinternals.com/) and searched for the log file to see what process had a lock on it. The process was POWERSHELL.EXE.  Hmmmm.  I thought, initially, that it might be the fact that I am writing the code in the PS ISE, which was open at the time, and somehow the ISE or a sub/meta system call had the lock.

So I tried running it with the ISE closed.  Same error.

I tried to see what process was locking it this time.  it was `<Non-existent Process>`.  My old friend.  However, time is money, right?  SO...

## THE FIX:

When you are ready to save the log - copy the log to a new file and Write this to the bucket:

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\TentacleInstallLog.txt -Destination D:\s3_TentacleInstallLog.txt -Force

Write-S3Object -bucketname mybucketnamehere -File D:\s3_TentacleInstallLog.txt -key ServerSetupLogs/$instanceId/TentacleInstallLog.txt
```

I feel dirty now.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like your file is being used by another process. So check the list of processes running , if there is any process which you suspect could be using this file kill that process.
File locking option is also available where you can make sure only one connection is established to you file or resource.

Hope this helps...